# How can I access the return of a Ruby response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I perform a method

```
a.kung_fu_this
```

And the method `kung_fu_this` returns an OpenStruct as a response in console. How would I access that information?

For example, lets say it returned an OpenStruct such as :

```
>> a.kung_fu_this
=> {Car: 'Mazda', Wood: 'Maple'}
```

Hpw can I capture that return and use it in another method?

Comment: `b = a.kung_fu_this` will set b equal to what `a.kung_fu_this` returns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply create a new variable and assign it the return of you method call,

```
returned_kung_fu = a.kung_fu_this
returned_kung_fu[:Car] # Mazda
```

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks sorry, brain dead today. Thank you for this

Comment: To answer your question more directly you can actually access the last returned results of irb by using the underscore `_`.

Comment: @Trip Do accept the answer if it solves your problem and help community to eliminate unanswered questions :)

Answer (score 3):

You can store it in a variable and then use it.

```
value = a.kung_fu_this
```